# Декодирование json с помощью PHP

Tags: php, json

Как правильно декодировать json такого вида?

```
[{"News": {
        "title": "\u041d\u0430\u0437\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435",
        "content": "\u0421\u043e\u0434\u0435\u0440\u0436\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435"
    }
}]
```

Мой код не работает

```
<?php
    $content = 'news'; // Указываем что нам нужны именно новости
    include_once('json.php'); // Запускаем скрипт json'а
    $content_decode = json_decode($list1); // Декодируем json

    foreach($content_decode->News as $text) {
        $title = $text->title;
        $content = $text->content;
        $main_content .= '
            <div id="title"><div id="title_text">'.$title.'</div></div>
            <div id="content"><div id="content_text">'.$content.'</div></div>';
    }

    echo '<html>
    <head>
        <title>W_0rld - Новости</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="../style/ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script>var limit = 10;</script>
    </head>

    <body onload="onload();">
        <div id="menu">
            <div id="logo" style=>W_0rld</div>
            <div id="links">
                <a class="news" href="/" id="link">Новости</a>
                <a class="list1" href="/page/1" id="link">Услуги</a>
                <a class="list2" href="/page/2" id="link">Заказать</a>
                <a class="list3" href="/page/3" id="link">Обо мне</a>
                <a href="//vk.com/W_0rld" id="link">ВК</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="container">'.$main_content.'</div>
        <div id="footer" style="display:none;">W_0rld - Новости</div>
    </body></html>';
```

Comment: вы пытаетесь использовать foreach по объекту. News - это **не** массив.

Comment: Не возникло проблем с декодированием, но воспроизвелась проблема, указанная Etki.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$json = '{

    "News": [

        {
            "title": "\u041d\u0430\u0437\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435",
            "content": "\u0421\u043e\u0434\u0435\u0440\u0436\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435"
        },
        {
            "title": "Head",
            "content": "Content"
        }
    ]
}';

$json = json_decode($json);

foreach($json->News as $new) {
    echo $new->title.', '.$new->content.'<br>';
}
```

`Название, Содержание`
`Head, Content`

---

```
$news = array("News" => array(
    array("title" => "Head", "content" => "Content")
));

$json = json_encode($news);
```

`var_dump($json);` `string(47) "{"News":[{"title":"Head","content":"Content"}]}"`

```
string(47) "{

    "News": [
        {
            "title": "Head",
            "content": "Content"
        }
    ]

}"
```

Comment: Я понял в чем моя проблема: мой json не валидный. Что надо поменять что-бы он стал валидным? Вот мой код: http://w-0rld.ru/download/1.txt

Comment: @W_0rld, добавил encode в ответ

Answer (score -2):

```
?php
$content = 'news'; // Указываем что нам нужны именно новости
include_once('json.php'); // Запускаем скрипт json'а
$content_decode = json_decode($list1); // Декодируем json

foreach($content_decode as $text) {
    $title = $text['title'];
    $content = $text['content'];
    $main_content .= '
        <div id="title"><div id="title_text">'.$title.'</div></div>
        <div id="content"><div id="content_text">'.$content.'</div></div>';
}
$content_decode -  это массив а не объект
```

Comment: В данном случае `$content_decode` это как раз объект. Для преобразования в ассоциативный массив `json_decode($json, true);`

Answer (score -3):

просто добавьте в `json_decode($json,true)` второй параметр true и функция будет возвращать всегда массив.